# Android : How may ways I can get current location programatically

Tags: android, geolocation

How many ways I can get the current geo location (lat,lang) programatically in Android, Which is the best, accurate and faster way??

Look forward to your suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Good posting I came across http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/226-android-location-providers-gps-network-passive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [**Obtaining User Location**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) in the SDK's documentation.

Comment: Not sure there is a *best* way : GPS can be slow, but is quite accurate ; cell is not precise but faster ; not all device have GPS ;;; using a combinaison of several ways is probably the best way *(first, celle-tower, to quickly have a location ; then GPS, so it gets more preceise)*

Comment: Thanks Pascal, any code example available for reference (Using both Network provider and GPS)

Comment: No, sorry ; there are samples in the manual, I suppose -- but I've never used them.

Comment: Good posting I came across http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/226-android-location-providers-gps-network-passive

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find out location via IP address:

http://www.google.com.sg/search?aq=1&oq=identifying+location&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=identifying+location+of+ip+addresses

Another method is by GSM, or control-plane locating, yet other methods can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-based_service#Others

Answer (score 0):

When developing a location-aware application for Android, you can utilize GPS and Android's Network Location Provider to acquire the user location. Although GPS is most accurate, it only works outdoors, it quickly consumes battery power, and doesn't return the location as quickly as users want. Android's Network Location Provider determines user location using cell tower and Wi-Fi signals, providing location information in a way that works indoors and outdoors, responds faster, and uses less battery power. To obtain the user location in your application, you can use both GPS and the Network Location Provider, or just one`

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            loc = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                          }
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        loc = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    }
```